# NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality forces containsObject: method to use isEqual: (doesn't work)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

```
closed = [[NSHashTable alloc]initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality capacity:4000000];
```

`[closed containsObject:someObject]` is not using isEqual method, not as apple's documentation describes, anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state that `NSPointerFunctionsObjectPersonality` uses `isEqual:`. The docs state that `NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality` uses "direct comparison to determine equality". I assume the latter means `==`.

So try using `NSPointerFunctionsObjectPersonality` to get checks with `isEqual:`.

Comment: That's right. The "Object" personality calls the -isEqual: method. The "ObjectPointer" personality uses == comparison on the pointer address.